# Let $0\lt a\lt b$ and $\mu \in \mathbb R$. Calculate $\int_a^b x^{\mu} dx$ by dividing the interval $[a, b]$ using geometric progression

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and the only relevant information I was able to find is
$$\text{Let } 0\lt a\lt b\text{ and }q=\sqrt[n]\frac ba$$
$$\text{then }\pi:a\lt aq\lt aq^2\lt\text{...}\lt aq^n=b$$
and I'm not sure how to use this in order to solve the question at all.

Important: One can assume that the function is Riemann-integrable without proof.

Comment: Can you calculate the Riemann sum corresponding to this integral using this partition?

Comment: I've been thinking of that but wouldn't that require some kind of limit on μ? Because for μ < 0 the function would decrease, right?

Comment: Why would you require a condition on $\mu$? By definition the Riemann sum of any function is$$\sum_i f(x_i^*)\Delta x_i\to\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$given that the function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: You're right. Just using the Riemann sum seems to work fine. Sorry for any inconveniences. I've updated the post with some information I missed.